# AJAX not passing values out to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am using Ajax to automatically update a $_SESSION value when a select option is used. Specifically, if a user selects a language from a dropdown list, $_SESSION['language'] must be update. This not happening with my implementation but I am not seeing why.

1) Select:

```
<select id="lang" name="lang">
                        <option value="en" data-reactid=".1.$en">English</option>
                        <option value="es" data-reactid=".1.$es">Español</option>
                        <option value="it" data-reactid=".1.$it">Italiano</option>
                        <option value="sv" data-reactid=".1.$sv">Svenska</option>
                    </select>
```

2) lang is passed to js and Ajax (post_language.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#lang').change(function() {
    var language_selection = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../includes/ajax/language_ajax.php',
        data: {lang: language_selection},
        success:function(data){
            alert('This was sent back: ' + language_selection);
            $('#lang').html(data);  
        },
        error:function(msg){
            console.log('error: '+msg);}
    });
});
```

});

At this point, the ALERT message appears correctly, HOWEVER, 'lang' never reaches $_SESSION echoed from within the url: language_ajax.php. In fact, the url is never even called by ajax.

3) language_ajax.php

```
if(isset($_POST['lang'])){

    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
    echo "Language " . $lang;
  }
```

I searched the forums for a few hours with no success. All solutions seem to not apply to the use of 'change' with a select list.

Can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: What is expected result? Text node `data` : `"Language " . $lang` is not valid child element of `<select>` element

Comment: Where's the session code? Question is incomplete

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question. Post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Why was my question downgraded? what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text node `data` : `"Language " . $lang` `echo`ed from `php` is not a valid child element of `<select>` element.

See [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

> Permitted content Zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements.

Comment: @user6358161 At Question _"At this point, the ALERT message appears correctly,"_ , you try to set `#lang` `.html()` to returned `data` at `success` : `$('#lang').html(data);` though `data` is text, which is not a valid child element of `<select>` element, resulting in existing `<option>` elements being removed and text node is still not set as `<select>` element `html`. You can use `$("body").append(data)` to append text node to `<body>` element, or other element, of `document`.

Comment: thanks @guest271314  the use of body solved the issue. However, what if I do not want to APPEND, but to overwrite the value at every new selection?

Comment: @user6358161 _"the use of body solved the issue. However, what if I do not want to APPEND, but to overwrite the value at every new selection?"_ You can create an element `<div class="lang"></div>` which can be used to render text node returned from `$.ajax()` request `$(".lang").text(data)`, see https://jsfiddle.net/hvyt3Lyx/1/

Comment: your solution worked in [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hvyt3Lyx/1/), but I had to replace `$(".lang").text(data);` with `$(".lang").text(language_selection);` for it to work correctly on my server.

Comment: @user6358161 What does `console.log(data)` log?

Comment: console.log(data) sends the ajax outgoing quantity to the console log file. I can then see that from console of the developer tool.

Comment: I thought your solution actually passed the ajax quantity to the url file, but no; what it does is only printing the quantity on screen with the use of "text".

The url file is still not accessed. Do you know why?

Comment: @user6358161 _"I thought your solution actually passed the ajax quantity to the url file"_ It does, see jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hvyt3Lyx/1/ . At your actual `js` use `data: {lang: language_selection},` instead of `{html: "Language " + language_selection}`

Comment: guest271314  my fault, yes, it accesses the url file correctly, but the $_POST['lang'] is empty though. Are you reading the quantity with a $_POST from your /home/html in [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hvyt3Lyx/1/) ?

Comment: _"but the $_POST['lang'] is empty though. Are you reading the quantity with a $_POST from your /home/html"_ What do you mean?

Comment: When ajax sends the value to the url file (language_ajax.php in my case, /echo/html/ in your case) that is called by ajax, the quantity 'lang' should be read in with a `$_POST['lang']`, but `$_POST['lang']` is empty for me.

Comment: @user6358161 How do you know `$_POST["lang"]` is empty? Just tried `js` at jsfiddle, `php` that you posted at original Question at `localhost` using `php` internal server http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php, returned same results as returned at jsfiddle. Are you receiving a `500` internal server error? Does your `php` file include `<?php` at first line of `'../includes/ajax/language_ajax.php'`?

Comment: no, I don't have a 500 internal error. Simply `Undefined index: lang` from within ../includes/ajax/language_ajax.php when I execute `echo "QUI?  " . $_POST["lang"];`

Comment: @user6358161 What is `index` at `index: lang`?

Comment: It is just the way the error handler print out a missing quantity error. In this case, that `$_POST['lang']` is not set.  In other words, `isset[$_POST['lang']` is false.

Comment: I found the error. I was reading 'lang' when, though, ajax was returning the quantity 'html'.

Comment: The error was the one described in my previous message. It is now solved and I will edit my post with the working solution.
It was a pleasure working with you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is that the whole of the language_ajax.php script? If so, you've not added any statements to update the $_SESSION['language'] value... for example:

```
if(isset($_POST['lang'])){

    $lang = $_POST['lang'];

    session_start();//Initialise Session
    $_SESSION['language'] = $lang;

    echo "Language " . $lang;
}
```

If as you say the php script is never even reached, surely 'success' in the JS wouldn't run?

Also, as others say, '$('#lang').html(data)' is completely invalid for a SELECT element. However, there's no need to update the SELECT value as it's just been updated by the user...

Comment: Hi @hakJav   the content of language_ajax.php is larger and the session is already started so that I omitted unnecessary information.

About 'success': success is true, in fat the alert window opens and prints the correct language. The problem here is that language_ajax.php is never reached.

Comment: If you check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, 'success' only runs if the request succeeds, so your server is being reached & sending back some data - what does the data read? Maybe your URL is incorrect and your server is sending back a 'file not found' error? In which case double check the URL you are calling - are you sure the URL is specifying the right location of the PHP file in relation to the current document?

Comment: the data reads what is expected, which is the value of the selection from select. I get no error in the log though.

Comment: I'm a little confused. - maybe you've confused yourself by writing: alert('This was sent back: ' + language_selection); - that's incorrect, as language_selection isn't sent back, you're just printing the JS variable you specified at the beginning. Try running alert('This was sent back: ' + data); -- or console.log('This was sent back: ' + data); would probably be better

Answer (score -1):

if you send data as "in body", you can take it below;

```
if (!is_array($_POST) || (count($_POST) < 1)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

Comment: OP not sending in body as json so what is the point of this? Default for `$.ajax` is sending form encoded data. Answer has nothing to do with the question